# Upgrade Azure Bot from qna template to enterprise bot template

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to upgrade my Azure bot with QnA template to Enterprise Bot Template. I'm following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0. As my understanding, the command `msbot clone services --name "YOUR_BOT_NAME" --luisAuthoringKey "YOUR_AUTHORING_KEY" --folder "DeploymentScripts\LOCALE_FOLDER" --location "REGION"` will create whole set of Azure service.

Can i use existing service such as Bot Service, QnA service instead of create new one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same bot service and QNA service. Do use the correct QNA name while configuring the service.